# Append API data to Pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am request data from the Zoopla API, going through each of the page and then finally trying to append the data in a dataframe. I am using the following code:

```
raw_data = pd.DataFrame([])

for i in range(1,5):
    r = requests.get('http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.json?area=Nottingham&api_key=my_key&page_size=20&page_number='+str(i))
    data = r.json()
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['listing'])
    raw_data.append(df_temp,ignore_index=True,sort=False)
```

The code above, however, doesn't append any data to raw_data at all.

```
raw_data.shape // returns (0,0) after the for loop.
```

Note: I haven't shared my API key in the url above. I can confirm that I am receiving data from the API

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are receiving data from requests?

Comment: I'm getting a 403 response from that page.

Comment: hey Daniel, yes I am. I haven't shared my API key publicly here. You will see in the URL I've replaced my API key with "my_key" @DanielScott

Comment: Great, and have you confirmed that it is real json? If the json snippet is small, can you post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append isn't an inplace operation by default. You can fix it by changing to

```
raw_data = raw_data.append(df_temp,ignore_index=True,sort=False)
```

Comment: this works. Thanks so much